# SharePoint list first row duplicates by itself over and over

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have a very strange situation that is driving me crazy. I created a custom list, and a web part (New Item) that I use to enter the info. But now all everytime I create a new record, the first row create new rows by itself.
[image]

As you can see in the image above. I created the item "aaaa" at 8:16 AM. Then by itself it created two more at 8:17 and 8:21. Then I created "bbbbbbb..", and as you can see "aaaa.." created another set of rows by itself, the same with "ddd.."

What could it be happening here? By the way I can't use "Enforce Unique Values". Some of the records may have the same names.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the "Created By" column and see who is creating it.  It might be a system generated row, somehow.

Comment: The "Created By" column shows the same person (me). I really don't know what is happening here. Thansk!

Comment: Do you have any workflows running?

Comment: No, no workflows on this list. I noticed that only the first row repeats itself. I may have to end up deleting all the rows, and creating a first row with a "defined" name such as "test" or something I can sort out whenver I need to run a report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that I refreshing the page. Apperantly this is known issue.